# Repeat BeautifulSoup scrape for all files in a local folder

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, export-to-csv

I have thousands of html files in a few folders that I want to pull the data from the comments and put into a csv file.  This will allow me to format and clean it for a project.  For example, I have 640 html files in this folder:

> D:\My Web Sites\baseball 2\www.baseball-reference.com\boxes\ANA

Here's my code pulling comments from a single file and putting into a CSV:

```
# import libraries and files
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import re
import csv

# Get Page, Make Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("D:/My Web Sites/baseball 2/www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ANA/ANA201806180.html"), 'lxml')

# Get Description
game_description = soup.findAll("div", {"scorebox_meta"})
print (game_description)

# Get Comment Data
Player_Data = soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment))
for c in Player_Data:
    print c
    print "==========="

# Results to CSV
csvfile = "C:/Users/Benny/Desktop/anatest.csv"

with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(Player_Data)
```

I need to pull the game data from each html file (all of it nested into comments in the html code), put the individual scrape results for each game file into a single CSV.  Any help with the code is super appreciated.

Thanks,
Benny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `os.listdir` module to iterate over all files in your dir. Alternately you can also use the `glob` module.

**Ex:**(`os.listdir`)

```
import os
path = r"D:\My Web Sites\baseball 2\www.baseball-reference.com\boxes\ANA"

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".html"):
        fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)

        # Get Page, Make Soup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(open(fullpath), 'lxml')
        .....
```

Comment: Thank you Rakesh, I'll give that a go.